# How to get currently selected item from QListWidget and not what it remembers

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

`QListWidget` returns on `.selectedItems()` even if there are no items currently selected (it remembers last item clicked or selected. So even if all its items were deselected it still returns what it remembers). But I need `QListWidget` to return ONLY that item that is currently selected.

`.hasFocus()` trick is not reliable since all the items could get hidden, QListWidget would be in focus. But it still will go ahead and return an item while nothing is selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you don't think that `.selectedItems()` doesn't work.  I just tried this with the code below and it's working correctly.

```
import sys

from PySide import QtGui


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()

        self.resize(720, 480)
        central_widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(central_widget)

        self.text_edit = QtGui.QTextEdit(central_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.text_edit)

        self.drop_list = QtGui.QListWidget(central_widget)
        self.drop_list.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
        self.drop_list.addItems(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'])
        self.drop_list.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.show_List)
        layout.addWidget(self.drop_list)

        statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(self)
        self.setStatusBar(statusbar)

        action_ShowList = QtGui.QAction(self)
        action_ShowList.triggered.connect(self.show_List)

        self.show()

    def show_List(self):
        self.text_edit.setText(repr(self.drop_list.selectedItems()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    frame = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Everything selected:

[image: All items in list selected]

Nothing selected:

[image: No items in list selected]

Comment: .selectedItems() returns the items even if there is nothing currently selected. It "remembers" things. If you select ListView item, then hide all the items, deselect everything, select another widget it will still return what was selected last time.

Comment: You'll need to share more of your code for me to understand what you're experiencing.  If you run my code above, there's not "remembrance" of items.

Comment: I've edited your code and posted it to show the problem I had. Please take a look it is appended under.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this approach:

```
def getSelectedItem(self):
    if not self.myTreeWidget.hasFocus(): return
    for selectedItem in self.myTreeWidget.selectedItems():
        if not selectedItem: continue
        if selectedItem.isHidden(): continue 
        return selectedItem
```

## Edited later:

Here is his code (edited) showing the problem I've mentioned.

First select an item, then hide all the items by hitting 'Hide-Unhide' button. Click anywhere inside of now being empty listView (just to make sure everything is deselected). Click "Print Selected" button. Here is the image of the result:

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.resize(720, 480)
        central_widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(central_widget)

        self.text_edit = QtGui.QTextEdit(central_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.text_edit)

        self.drop_list = QtGui.QListWidget(central_widget)

        self.drop_list.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
        self.drop_list.addItems(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'])
        layout.addWidget(self.drop_list)
        self.show()

        self.button1=QtGui.QPushButton("Hide-Unhide Items")
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.hideUnhideItems)
        layout.addWidget(self.button1)

        self.button2=QtGui.QPushButton("Print Selected")
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.getSelected)
        layout.addWidget(self.button2)

    def getSelected(self):
        self.text_edit.clear()
        self.text_edit.setText(repr(self.drop_list.selectedItems()))

    def hideUnhideItems(self):
        for i in range(self.drop_list.count()):
            item=self.drop_list.item(i)
            if not item.isHidden():
                item.setHidden(True)
            else:
                item.setHidden(False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    frame = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Well of course it's still going to be selected.  It's never deselected!  Only hidden.

Comment: BTW you need to add this to your question and not as an answer.  then delete this answer.

Comment: Strange and misleading that even after QListWidget is clicked (with all items being hidden) it still keeps thinking the last selected item is `selected`...

Comment: Well of course it's still selected!  It's just hidden.  You need to deselect it before hiding it if you don't want them to be selected anymore.